# Use .xsd file validate data

Tags: c#

I use .XSD file to validate data format, the string fields should allow only digits. There is the code I used:

```
<xs:element name="OrderPurgeDays">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="3"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]+"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

it didn't work.

```
<OrderPurgeDays>a00</OrderPurgeDays>
```

the data like above can also insert into database.Is there any thing wrong that I don't know?

By the way, I use below code

```
`SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad` objBL = 
                     new SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad();

objBL.ConnectionString = DatabaseConnection;
objBL.KeepIdentity = true;
objBL.CheckConstraints = true;
objBL.XMLFragment = true;
```

import the data to database.

Or, is there any other way to validate data format before bulk import data into database by

```
SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad
```

requirement is that string field should be digit.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that; the specified simple type won't accept `a00` on [this schema validation service](http://xsdvalidation.utilities-online.info/), for example. Are you sure your schema is evaluated as desired?

Comment: Can you add the execute command line of code as well to your question?

Comment: Hi danish, I paste my code here: string DatabaseConnection = "provider=SQLOLEDB;data source=.;database=XXX;integrated security=SSPI";
            SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad objBL = new SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad();
            objBL.ConnectionString = DatabaseConnection;
            objBL.KeepIdentity = true;
            objBL.CheckConstraints = true;
            objBL.XMLFragment = true;
            // objBL.ErrorLogFile = @".\log\SQLXMLBulkLoadError.log";          
                objBL.Execute("Schema.xsd", "data.xml");

Answer (score -1):

OrderPurgeDate is supposed to have number from 000 through 999 as strings. Either change the Pattern is the property is supposed to have alphanumeric values or change the datatype to integer and restriction to limit values to 999.

Comment: The pattern as depicted should work. `a00` is not a string that can only contain between one and three decimal digits, as described by the pattern, so something else must be the problem here.

Comment: XSD pattern is a regular expression. [0-9]+ means the value should only have numbers and not alphabets. Hence, a00 does not qualify.

Comment: Exactly. The OP's question is why `a00` can be added even though it should be ruled out by the pattern. As both you and I agree, the pattern is correct and indeed should rule out `a00`, so suggesting to change the pattern does not explain the problem at hand.